# How to structure a HTML/JS iPad application for best performance?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, uiwebview

I'm developing a HTML-based iPad application that makes heavy use of JavaScript for its UI. GUI is going to be magazine-like i.e. chopped into screens/views that the user then navigates between with touch events and webkit transitions. All of this runs locally on an iPad (via a native wrapper such as PhoneGap, etc.).

Lets say the application is going to have 50-100 of those screens - filled with standard web elements like text, images, tables and forms.

How to structure that for best performance? Which of the following 2 methods is preferable and why?

1. having only 3 immediate (current, previous, next) views/screens in DOM and then appending new ones (and deleting the old ones) into DOM as the user navigates forward/backward?
2. having the entire 50-100 HTML screens generated at start and then hiding (display:none) all of them but the above 3

So basically what works better memory/performance-wise? From one side continuous DOM operations might be costly (and worse make the transitions between app screens jerky) - and from the other side - don't know if having up to a 100 HTML screens pre-generated in a single document DOM won't make Mobile Safari choke to death. Of course even though those screens are in DOM, most of them are display:none most of the time - but is the mobile safari garbage collector that good? Has anyone tried this out?

**BTW please note that this is not an image-memory problem/leak type question. I'm aware of that problem and will be handling it via small-dummy-image unloading trick no matter which way I go. This is only about HTML views - skeletons if you will.**

Answer (score 0):

If the content is all going to be downloaded to the device at the time of launch, and everything is locally cached, then definitely go with the first method, as it will have a significantly smaller memory footprint.

If the content is downloaded on the fly, however, I would go with a mix between 1 and 2... probably prefetching and rendering the next two or three slides in either direction, or maybe one in each direction and one for each link on the page.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is local - no downloading (other than the images which are going to downloaded only once anyway and then cached). However are you sure constant DOM append/remove is preferable to navigating between inserted screens (I'm thinking this might help also make hardware-accelerated transform3d transitions smoother?)? Shouldn't display:none help keep the memory footprint small?